# Передача переменной между сценами

Tags: swift, spritekit

Сама себя запутала, можете помочь, пытаюсь передать переменную из одной сцены в другую вроде все правильно делала, а передать не могу https://yadi.sk/d/5a0z5_1_udACZ

Comment: из какой в какую? куда смотреть?

Comment: Переменную score из GameScene в Menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы его в меню грузите, но нигде не сохраняете

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "score")
```

Comment: Точно, вот что забыла, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: вы удивительный человек :)

Comment: И такое бывает=D

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод: `prepareForSegue`. Примерно так:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "YourSceneId") {
           var newController = segue!.destinationViewController as secondScene;
           newController.variableName = newValue
        }
    }
```

Урок по теме [тут](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/).

Comment: У меня SpriteKit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18924419/608343